# Google Cloud vs. Google App Engine for a beginner?

Tags: google-app-engine, server

Which do you think is easier for a beginner who lacks of knowledge of setting up a server?

Or, in other words: if I want to start a website, is learning the infrastructure of Google App Engine or learning the normal way to host a website easier?

I have spent some time learning Django, Python, AngularJS and Google App Engine.

Comment: Please search what is PaaS and VM ( Dedicated Server )

Comment: *the normal way*? What is the normal way?

Comment: @RajaSimon I think I know the difference between PaaS and VM. I just want to know which is easier for a beginner. Because I think Apache & wsgi are pretty hard to understand. So do the blobstore of Google App Engine.

Comment: Hi, @TimCastelijns , I mean Apache, python with wsgi, node.js with mongodb or other ways to host a server on Linux machines.

Comment: Appengine also has python and wsgi, also *is learning the infrastructure of Google App Engine* you don't have to deal with the infrastructure, google does it for you

Comment: App Engine: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ckVyxODiTIo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AppEngine** is **PaaS** - you can host there your apps. So you do not have to deal with the servlet container, datastore, cron jobs, scaling etc.

**Compute Engine** is Google's **IaaS** - you get a VM and you can do with it whatever you like.

Basically these 2 are completely 2 different things, for different use cases. What do you have? an app? or do you need to install other things on the machine? After you come up with answers to this, you will have the answer...

Comment: Thanks, I just want to make an app.